# JWT encoding and claims publicity

Tags: jwt

I know that it was discussed widely but I can't sum on what I read.

Is it correct that JWT is put to HTTP headers without encoding? Only being signed on. So that's common practice that token data (claims) is open and only signature allows to check whether JWT is reliable. From the point of view of keeping details in secrete people rely on HTTS.

Correct?

Comment: JWT is signed and encrypted before being appended to the header. So claims are not open.

Comment: @RyanWilson do you mean JWE? Or just encryption of compacted JWS?

Comment: JWE is encrypted (hence the E), but the "normal" JWT in form of a signed token (JWS) is just base64url encoded and signed. So header and payload of the tokenare easily readable, e.g on https://jwt.io. @RyanWilson please clarify what you mean.